# RemoteReader Plugin is not working on server

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

I am trying to install RemoteReader on our server. I was able to run it on local pc but with same config it is not running on live.

I am using http://www.keytours.com/remote/totalstay.ivector.co.uk/Content/DataObjects/PropertyReference/Image/ext189/image_188557_v1.jpg?w=75&h=75&mode=crop to rezise images according to your documentation as this link http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/remotereader (human-friendly syntax).

I am  also attaching diagnostic result of our server from gist

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/74f7d66daba5920149e4

Comment: What code are you using for RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.AllowRemoteRequest?

Comment: I am using asp.net and c# I have in global.asax

ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader.RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.AllowRemoteRequest += Current_AllowRemoteRequest;

and

static void Current_AllowRemoteRequest(object sender, ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader.RemoteRequestEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.RemoteUrl.StartsWith("http://remotesite.com/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            args.DenyRequest = false;
    }

Comment: Log the values of args.RemoteUrl to disk, and compare the two on your remote server and local machine.

Comment: Also, shouldn't "remotesite.com/" be "totalstay.ivector.co.uk" instead? Are you quite sure this same code worked locally?

Comment: yeah. I changed the url. actual url is totalstay.ivector..co.uk. Yeah it is working on local.

Comment: Have you compared the incoming values of args.RemoteUrl between local and your server?

Comment: I think code on our servers is not hit RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.AllowRemoteRequest function in global.asax. I try to log the urls but log file is empty.

Comment: are you there? would you like to help me?

Comment: we are using UrlScan on our server. it was blocking dots in url. so we made AllowDotInPath settings to 1. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When production behaves differently than development, start reducing differences between the two until you solve the problem. Preferably, have a staging server that is 100% identical to production, so you can test and debug without downtime.

> we are using UrlScan on our server. it was blocking dots in url. so we
>   made AllowDotInPath settings to 1. It solved the issue.